# Word meaning "to fall down accidentally?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The bridge's parapet was thick so I could sit on it without
>   feeling dizzy, fear of [...] down.

Is there another word other than *fall*? I thought of *tumbling* but I think you can only tumble down a slope not a free fall.

Comment: Typos: *bridge's*; *slope*. I'm a little unsure about "feeling vertigo"; I'd say *feeling dizzy* or *the sensation of [vertigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertigo)*

Comment: @Mari-Lou A OK, fixed. But I think *vertigo* is a type of dizziness? Hence something you feel?

Comment: Vertigo is dizziness or lightheadedness. You feel dizzy when you **have** vertigo. You feel nauseous when you have nausea.

Comment: **tumble** is completely fine.

Answer (score 9):

If you use *fall* with the preposition *off*, it emphasizes that it is an accidental or unintentional fall.

The difference between *fall off* and *fall down* would be that, you fall off when you are on something. *Fall down* doesn't indicate that you are on something.

> **fall off** *vb (intr)*
>   to drop unintentionally to the ground from (a high object, bicycle, etc), esp after losing one's balance
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall+off</sup>

Example:

> Your fear of falling off the bridge is a fear of antigravity, of losing your sense of your physical location in space. Of becoming nonlocal. One's sense of location is a fundamental sense, just like hearing, which is so closely allied with it.
>
> [Black Hole Butterfly *By Salem* (2014)]

Answer (score 7):

*Slip* is the only word I can think of that implies a fall was accidental, but I don't think it quite fits in your example.  There's really nothing wrong with just using "fall" in that instance, but if you really want another word you might try *plummet* or *plunge*.

Comment: plummet or plunge are probably what Jano is after!

Answer (score 3):

**Slip**?

From Merriam Webster

> ***slip*** (verb) - to fall into error or fault
>
> The bridge' parapet was thick so I could sit on it without feeling vertigo, fear of slipping off.

Comment: I believe that definition of slip refers to making a mistake, like a 'slip of the tongue'.  In terms of falling, slip usually implies a slippery or slick surface, which didn't jump to mind when thinking of a bridge parapet.  That said, I do agree it implies an accidental fall.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think *tumble* is limited to slopes?

> *[American Heritage](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/tumble)*:
>
> - To fall or roll end over end: The kittens tumbled over each other.
> - To spill or roll out in confusion or disorder: Students tumbled out of the bus.
> - To pitch headlong; fall: tumbled on the ice.
> - To proceed haphazardly.
> - To topple, as from power or a high position; fall.
> - To collapse: The wall tumbled down.
> - To drop: Prices tumbled.
>
> *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tumble)*
>
> to fall or cause to fall, esp awkwardly, precipitately, or violently
>
> *[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tumble)*:
>
> - to fall down suddenly and quickly
> - to fall forward while turning over

But also consider

- topple
- keel over
- cascade

Comment: +1 for *topple* which expresses the idea of falling due to unsteadiness. But if you are also suggesting *tumble* (because it is appropriate) I would put the word in bold or in italics if I were you.

Comment: Dictionary definitions notwithstanding, I think ***tumble*** (which I consider to be a rather dated/literary usage) does strongly suggest *rolling over and over, repeatedly bouncing off the ground while falling down a slope*. And noting things like ***tumbleweed***, I have to say that the sense of ***rolling along*** can completely eclipse the ***falling down*** component. No such issues arise with ***topple***, which *always* implies going ***down***.

Answer (score 0):

*Stumble*. It means to trip on accidentally.

Answer (score -1):

Another would be "trip" ("a stumble; misstep.").